# Run sms app for result

Tags: android, sms

Hello I would like to make app using android sms app, flow i want to have is:

My app -> Android SMS App(native, handcent, etc) ->(after sending message) My app (check if sms was sent).

I know that it is possible on iPhone, but what with android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found that this is impossible using native app. I can do this inside own app only.